# Is it possible to write fizzbuzz using only 2 checks?

Tags: algorithm

the obvious solution is something like:

```
if (x % 15 == 0) println("fizzbuzz");
else if (x % 3 == 0) println ("fizz");
else if (x % 5 == 0) println ("buzz");
```

then you could say that the trick is to concatenate fizz and buzz:

```
if (x % 3 == 0) print("fizz");
if (x % 5 == 0) print("buzz");
if (x % 15 == 0) println();
```

or

```
print("%s%s%s", x % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" : "", x % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" : "", x % 15 == 0 ? "\r\n" : "");
```

so the problem is the line break, and in all of the above cases we are performing 3 checks.

assuming that there needs to be a line break after either "fizz", or "buzz", how can it be done using only 2 checks?

Comment: What's a "check"? One has to work surprisingly hard to keep the minimum number needed from being zero.

Comment: "fizzbuzz" is a popular interview question, there's plenty of information on the web about it. It typically tests that an applicant is able to read a specification, validate the specification (it is usually worded so that it's slightly ambiguous as to whether you need to output *both* fizz and buzz when both hit, used to ensure the applicant knows to ask for clarification), and that the applicant is able to write working code. You'd be surprised how many that turns in their CV's for job positions fails the fizzbuzz (or similar) tests.

Comment: checks are not just 3, they are actually 300 (considering no compiler optimizations)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about no checks?

```
string[] output = { "fizzbuzz", "", "", "fizz", "", "buzz", "fizz", "", "", "fizz", "buzz", "", "fizz", "", "" };
print("%s", output[x % 15]);
```

Note that this of course only removes `if` statements from *this* code. The underlying code will most likely contain a jump instruction or two.

If you want to make it a bit clearer what is happening you can create two arrays:

```
string[] fizz = { "fizz", "", "" };
string[] buzz = { "buzz", "", "", "", "" };
print("%s%s", fizz[x % 3], buzz[x % 5]);
```

Note that both of these implementations will not handle negative numbers, here's a version that does:

```
string[] fizz = { "fizz", "", "" };
string[] buzz = { "buzz", "", "", "", "" };
print("%s%s", fizz[((x % 3) + 3) % 3], buzz[((x % 5) + 5) % 5]);
```

Note that I have neatly skipped over the newline you added in your code. If you want that, I'm sure you can figure out how to modify the above code in the same manner to add it :)

**More importantly**: Note that this does in fact *not* pass the "official" fizzbuzz test, it only answers your question.

The fizzbuzz test is this:

- Write out all numbers from 1 to 100, except that numbers that are multiplies of 3 you should *instead of the number* write out "fizz", and that for numbers that are multiplies of 5 you should *instead of the number* write out "buzz". If a number is a multiple of *both* 3 and 5 at the same time, write out "fizzbuzz" instead of the number.

Since your question did not in any way handle the "instead of the number" part, my answer did not either.

So, if we skip the fact that a loop usually entails a "check", can we write the entire fizzbuzz test without if-statements?

With a bit of magic, yes we can, here's the loop in C# code, you can verify this using [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) or [Ideone](http://ideone.com/5GSwD7):

```
void Main()
{
    string[] fizzbuzz = new[]
    {
        "fizzbuzz", "{0}", "{0}", "fizz", "{0}", "buzz", "fizz",
        "{0}", "{0}", "fizz", "buzz", "{0}", "fizz", "{0}", "{0}"
    };
    for (int index = 1; index <= 100; index++)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(fizzbuzz[index % 15], index));
    }
}
```

Here I'm relying on the fact that the format string sent to `string.Format` does in fact not have to contain any references to the arguments.

**Edit**: As stated in the comments, I had used `??` to get the `"{0}"` in the `string.Format` parameter and leaving the entries in the array at `null`, but `??` is indeed an if-statement in disguise, so edited it out.

Comment: `??` not being an "if" doesn't pass the smell test for me.

Comment: It could be done simpler if you just turn logic operation result in index (or just use C or C++). This way you need 3 arrays of len 2.

Comment: @LukaRahne Please post such a solution, I'm unsure what you mean here.

Comment: You could also avoid the redundancy in the array by using switch / case. Or just upvote my answer, which is just a one-liner and scales better to larger numbers... :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "switch / case", but a normal C# switch { } block is of course full of "checks".

Comment: Well it depends on your definition of "checks". If you see a table lookup from a table of n as n checks, then that amounts to n checks. I wouldn't argue that way, though -- in particular if I had answered the question with a table lookup with n = 15 :)

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen , check my answer

Comment: @LukaRahne that's another matter entirely. I was just trying to make an important point that 'cleverly' obfuscated code is not a good model for production code.

Comment: There is no irony in the OP's question. You missed the point entirely about the fizzbuzz test, and especially about such additional criteria. The fizzbuzz test, in its original form, is meant to filter out candidates for an interview that are only wasting your time. On top of that, if you add such additional criteria, you test whether the candidate can think outside the box. *That's* an important quality. Other than that the entire test is contrived to put it mildly so there is probably no production code looking like this anywhere, so you're pretty safe in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

"Only two checks" probably aims at the fact that if a number can be divided by 3 and by 5, this implies that the number can be divided by 15.

Sample code exploiting that (with only one check):

```
var words = ["fizzbuzz", "buzz", "fizz"];
var index = Math.min(x % 3, 1) + Math.min(x % 5, 1) * 2;
if (index < words.length) println(words[index]);
```

Note that Lasse's "How about no checks" answer still prints the empty string, which seems to be different from the original code and one of the main problems stated in the question.

If it's ok to include the newline in the text instead of using println(), this will do the work without checks:

```
print(["fizzbuzz\n", "buzz\n", "fizz\n", ""]
         [Math.min(x % 3, 1) + Math.min(x % 5, 1) * 2]);
```

P.S.

Since you asked for exactly two checks:

```
print(["fizzbuzz\n", "buzz\n", "fizz\n", ""]
         [(x % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1) + (x % 5 == 0 ? 0 : 2)]);
```

P.P.S.:

jsfiddle for the full FizzBuzz (including printing numbers): http://jsfiddle.net/QxDfh/

Comment: I took the liberty of fleshing out your code in [LINQPad](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzao6645983e7bo/SO17502946b.linq) to include the full FizzBuzz test (ie. the numbers as well), here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzao6645983e7bo/SO17502946b.linq

Comment: Thanks. I have added a jsfiddle for that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of codegolfing, but it works

```
for x in range(1,101):print"Fizz"[x%3*4:]+"Buzz"[x%5*4:]or x
```

Source: http://maxburstein.com/blog/python-shortcuts-for-the-python-beginner/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution without any conditional expression written in c. (except shortcircut evaluation)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fizzbuzz(int i)
{
    const char* f[]={"%i\n","fizz\n","buzz\n","fizbuzz\n"};
    return i&&fizzbuzz(i-1)&&printf(f[!(i%3)|!(i%5)*2],i)||1;
}
int main()
{
    return fizzbuzz(100); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I did FizzBuzz this was what I wanted to do and this is what I came up with:

```
        string[] p = { "", "Fizz", "Buzz", "FizzBuzz" };
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            p[0] = i.ToString();
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                n += 1;
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                n += 2;
            Console.WriteLine(p[n]);
            n = 0;
        }
```

The idea is to print the right string in the array by adding 1 for Fizz and 2 for Buzz, thus getting 3 if both are correct giving FizzBuzz in the array. This way the words can be anything rather than just a combination of the first two words. Let's say you wanted Fizz, Buzz and FizzieBuzzie it would still work by simply changing [3] in the array. Also for every time through the loop I change [0] to be the current number and that gets printed if nothing is added.

I wrote a more in depth blog post about my thought process here:

http://tomasforsman.com/blog/2018/04/19/fizzbuzz-challenge-in-c/

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site. If you do so, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's often considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [some tips and advice about self-promotion](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Given that you do state "My thought process ...", it's really close to disclosure, but would be better as something like "My thought process can be found on my site:".

Comment: Given the way this is structured, it feels quite a bit like you are intending it as a leader to pull people into your site (i.e. spam), rather than an real attempt to answer the question here. Sure, if there's stuff that's difficult to explain with the limited formatting and space available here, it's OK to link to an outside site with significantly more complete explanation, but the basics should be here. Right now, this just feels like a teaser to get people to click-through to your site.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I appreciate your understanding that I'm not yet fully familiar with all the nuances of how to answer in the best possible way. I've edited the answer, hopefully I've corrected all of the problematic areas you brought up. 

My intention was not at all to promote my blog, I have no revenues at all from it and it's simply a way for me to collect my thoughts. After doing the FizzBuzz challenge I simply tried to find if others had solved it in similar ways and in that process I found this question. I just stupidly kinda figured the code to be self explanatory. 
Cheers =)